# make parameter to change directory before it does anything

Tags: makefile

Are there any command line parameters for make to change to a directory before it does anything?

I have a case where I have to run make from a different directory than the Makefile. But since some source header include paths are relative to the Makefile directory, it cannot find those.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you edit the makefile to fix it? Or to include a `vpath`/`VPATH`?

Comment: I do not own the makefile and hence cannot edit it. Is the vpath a parameter to make?

Comment: No, they are makefile directives. Back to the first question, why do you need to do this? Are you trying to enforce a `builddir != srcdir` sort of thing?

Comment: The scenario is a Jenkins plugin where it is possible only to enter only make commands from workspace root and cannot change dir to subfolders

Comment: ok, this does the trick, make -C <dir>

Comment: `-C` tells make to change directories *before* reading any makefiles. That isn't the same thing you were asking for. Or, if it was what you were asking for your question was badly explained.

Comment: sorry,i agree it could have been explained better, will edit

Comment: The question description still doesn't match with what `-C` does but <shrug>. If `-C` does what you want then post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'make -C ' does the trick. It tells make to change directory before reading any makefiles as commented by Etan above.